# How can I calculate the bounding box of a 3D model?

Tags: opengl, collision-detection, models, blender, bounding-boxes

I am making a game in OpenGL and Blender and trying to use JBullet as the collision manager. I am using `BoxShape`s for collisions, which requires a `javax.vecmath.Vector3f` representing half of the box to create.

How do I calculate the dimensions (width, depth and height) of a Blender model in-game?

Comment: You need to find MBB of your model as it seems, why did you go into jbullet and physics in your question? Do you want to use MBB as collision body of your 3D model? Please clarify the question and delete unneccessary parts, however if you are using a lib to use OpenGL or using an inline C part please tell, also tell what is the format of your 3D model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're reading the model into your game, you'll be iterating through each vertex of the model. Simply keep track of the max/min for each X, Y and Z axes. Using these values you can find the center of your model as well as the extents. The width is the distance between X min and X max, the depth and height are similarly calculated depending on which axis you're using for which dimension.

Comment: Ok, so i am supposed to get the minimum vertex and the higest one for XYZ to get the measures. How exactly is that done? I am using OBJ's exported from blender.

Comment: We'd have to know how you're processing the vertices when you import a model. It sounds like you're making your own engine, so at some point, you'd be iterating through all the vertices of your model to read in their positions from a file to memory. That is the time when you'd want to read the position of each and get the minimum and maximum.

Comment: I am using(primarily) the engine made by ThinMatrix. In the engine, there is a method which prosesses the entire model(in OBJ format).

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Then you need to consult the documentation of the engine you're using to determine how to retrieve the information you're interested in.